# VB.Net: Display total when check boxes are checked

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, checkbox, include

I am making a EXP multiplier for a game, so when i key in an amount, i will tick the certain multiplier and it will multiply my EXP to display how much EXP i will earn.

I want to be able to know how to include statement if i check the checkbox so that the statement will be included, else it will not affect anything.

AIM:
i want the amount that i key in, which is exp, to multiply by 2 if system checkbox is checked. In which `system = checkbox1` and the total exp to multiply by 1.5x if 'hs = checkbox4' is checked. And if both is checked, total exp will multiply by 2x1.5= 3. Else, it is just 2x or 1.5x. But i do not know how to do that.

For example(i do not know how to write it but it is something around the point i want)

```
    system = exp * 2
    hs = exp * (50 / 100)


    If CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
        totalexp INCLUDES multiplier system
    ElseIf CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked Then
        totalexp is not affected by multiplier system
    End If
    If CheckBox4.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
        totalexp INCLUDES multiplier hs
    ElseIf CheckBox4.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked Then
        totalexp INCLUDES multiplier hs
    End If

    totalexp = hs * system
```

Please help!

Comment: If i understood your question right, you wanted to multiply your input with a certain rate if a certain checkbox is checked and display it, correct?

Comment: yes! that is right and if the checkbox is not checked it will not affect anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing you have `TextBox1` as your `exp` input and two check boxes which are `CheckBox1` and `CheckBox4` for `system` and `hs` respectively and a button to process the input then you can have this code below.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim exp As Double
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
        exp = CDbl(TextBox1.Text)
    Else
        MsgBox("Please input a number.")
    End If
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        exp = exp * 2
    End If
    If CheckBox4.Checked = True Then
        exp = exp * 1.5
    End If
    If exp <> 0 Then
        MsgBox(exp)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

If both check boxes are checked then your input (`exp`) will be multiplied by 2 AND 1.5.

If neither of the check boxes are checked, the display message will be zero. If you want that no message will be displayed once there will be no check box checked then you can add this right after the last `End If` code

change `MsgBox(exp)` to

```
If exp<> 0 Then
    MsgBox(exp)
End If
```

Comment: i have tried it but when both checkboxes are checked, i want the exp input to multiply by both, which is 2 x 1.5 = 3 but it does not work here

Comment: yes it works now, but can i ask if i add in more multipliers will it still work?

Comment: yeah it will. just follow the concept of the codes provided above. by the way, please accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: yes, definitely! but how do i change msg box to label text for this?

Comment: just add a label and do it this way for example>> label1.Text = exp